# how can I binding SfMaskedEdit from Syncfusion in xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, syncfusion

I am working with Syncfusion and its control SfMaskedEdit, I have problems to make the binding to a property in my viewModel; I tried something like this:

```
        <StackLayout BindingContext="{Binding PagePrueba}">
        <syncfusion:SfMaskedEdit x:Name="maskedEdit"                                
                                 Keyboard="Telephone" 
                                 MaskType="RegEx" 
                                 Mask="+1(\d{3})\d{7}" 
                                 ValueChanged="MaskedEdit_OnValueChanged"/>
```

But it's not working. it gives me an error MaskedEdit_OnValueChanged not fund. Even if in my viewModel I have

```
        private void MaskedEdit_OnValueChanged(object sender, Syncfusion.XForms.MaskedEdit.ValueChangedEventArgs e)
```

if I do this with a normal entry

```
<Entry Text="{Binding TelephoneNumber}"></Entry>
```

it works perfectly. Here is the documentation of the control:
 [Syncfusion](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfmaskededit/getting-started)

thank you all for your time

Comment: apparently I have to use ValueChanged = "MaskedEdit_OnValueChanged" and create the private void method MaskedEdit_OnValueChanged (object sender, Syncfusion.XForms.MaskedEdit.ValueChangedEventArgs e)
The problem I have is that I'm using the MVVM model and placing the MaskedEdit_OnValueChanged method in my viewModel page gives me an error MaskedEdit_OnValueChanged not fund; Will I have to do something with the BindingContext?

Answer (score 2):

I have checked with your query to bind a property in view model using SfMaskedEdit. To achieve this, you can bind the Value property of SfMaskedEdit control with view model property.

In ViewModel class:

```
    class MaskedEditViewModel
    {
    private string valueText;
    public string ValueText
    {
        get
        {
            return valueText;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(value); 
        }
    }

    private void SetValue(string data)
    {
        valueText = data;
        Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", string.Format("The current value is {0}", data),"OK");
    }
    }
```

XAML

```
<syncfusion:SfMaskedEdit Mask="00/00/0000" ValidationMode="KeyPress" 
x:Name="maskedEdit" Value="{Binding ValueText}">
```

You can find the sample from below
http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/MaskedEdit_MVVM938250655